# sendmail not sending subject and message body

Tags: sendmail

I am using this to send an email. Email is being sent but doesn't have subject and message in it. I have tested `${MAIL_SUBJECT}` and `${MESSAGE}` have correct values.

```
echo "From: ${MAIL_FROM} \nTo: ${MAIL_TO} \nSubject: ${MAIL_SUBJECT} \n${MESSAGE}" | /var/qmail/bin/sendmail -f ${MAIL_FROM} ${MAIL_TO}
```

Can anybody let me know how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'd call it a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168232/what-is-the-format-for-piping-a-message-into-sendmail , but there seems to be another mistake in your line as well.

- you may need to use the `-e` option to `echo`, as per the link above. From the manpage:

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Note that I don't have this problem on OS X, and this likely does not apply to BSD. But it doesn't hurt either.

- There needs to be two newlines between the subject line and the mail message. That is, an empty line.

Thus, the following may work properly:

```
echo -e "From: ${MAIL_FROM} \nTo: ${MAIL_TO} \nSubject:${MAIL_SUBJECT}"\
"\n\n${MESSAGE}" | /var/qmail/bin/sendmail -f ${MAIL_FROM} ${MAIL_TO}
```